# How to create a line to be draggable object?

Tags: .net, graphics, line

I created a line by keeping start point and end point.
Currently, if I want to move start point or end point, I must click at some point for move a point.

But sometime I don't want to change a distance of start and end point.
So I want to click at a line between two points for move a line and move line's position.

How to make a line to be object? How to handle if user click at the line?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class drawing a line:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace BaseClasses
{
    public class MyLine : Control
    {
        private int _lineSize = 1;
        [DefaultValue(typeof(int), "1")]
        public int LineSize
        {
            get
            {
                return _lineSize;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != _lineSize)
                {
                    _lineSize = value;
                    MinimumSize = new Size(_lineSize, _lineSize);
                    if (Parent != null)
                        Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        private LineOrientation _orientation = LineOrientation.Diag1;
        [DefaultValue(typeof(LineOrientation), "Diag1")]
        public LineOrientation Orientation
        {
            get
            {
                return _orientation;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _orientation)
                {
                    _orientation = value;
                    if (Parent != null)
                        Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        private Color _lineColor = Color.Black;
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
        public Color LineColor
        {
            get
            {
                return _lineColor;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != _lineColor)
                {
                    _lineColor = value;
                    if (Parent != null)
                        Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        public MyLine()
        {
            TabStop = false;
        }

        protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnParentChanged(e);
            if (Parent != null)
                this.BackColor = this.Parent.BackColor;
        }

        protected override void OnParentBackColorChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnParentBackColorChanged(e);
            this.BackColor = this.Parent.BackColor;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(_lineColor, _lineSize))
            {
                if (_orientation == LineOrientation.Diag1)
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, _lineSize - 1, _lineSize - 1, Width - _lineSize, Height - _lineSize);
                else if (_orientation == LineOrientation.Diag2)
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, _lineSize - 1, Height - _lineSize, Width - _lineSize, _lineSize - 1);
                else if (_orientation == LineOrientation.Horiz)
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, _lineSize - 1, (Height - _lineSize) / 2, Width - _lineSize, (Height - _lineSize) / 2);
                else if (_orientation == LineOrientation.Vert)
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, (Width - _lineSize) / 2, Height - _lineSize, (Width - _lineSize) / 2, _lineSize - 1);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);
            Invalidate();
        }

    }

    public enum LineOrientation { Diag1, Diag2, Vert, Horiz }
}
```

The click event should be handled at base class level (Control) and determining if the click occurs on the line or elsewhere.